# 'Error 404 Page not found' api REST-FRAMEWORK

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I've just started using rest-framework and I can't get my page to display.I have a 404 error the page was not found but when I arrive on the home page it knows the destination url . I've added my app in setting.py, I've done my serializer in serializer.py. I've tried all the solutions I've found on stack overflow but nothing works. I'll take any advice and solution you can offer, thank you in advance for your time.
(this is my first question on a forum if there are things that are not correct do not hesitate to point them out to me )

```
lesite/
|--urls.py
|
|--recup_fichier_api/
    |
    |---urls.py
    |---views.py
```

lesite\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("backend_recup_fichier/", include("backend_recup_fichier.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("page_accueil/",include("page_accueil.url")),
    path('table_config/', include('recup_fichier_api.urls'))
    
]
```

lesite\recup_fichier_api\views.py

```
class table_configVisewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet) : 
    queryset =  table_config.objects.all()
    serializer_class = config_serializer
```

lesite\recup_fichier_api\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

]
router = routers.DefaultRouter
router.register = ('table_config', table_configVisewset )
```